# UI Multitouch Architecture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multi-touch

I am developing a game with multitouch controllers. But I have problems with UI Image multi touching

I want to create this architecture.

[image: I want to create this architecture]

- Green Cycles will work as button. (Touch End)
- Red Cycle will work as a button.I need touch move or touch stay events for serial shoting. (Touch Move | Touch Stay)
- Yellow Box will work as a touchpad(UI Image Element). When finger moves over the box, It will trigger to Rotate method.

I tried some methods but all is failed.

I created a class named MultiTouchElement.

```
var touches = Input.touches;
for (int i = 0; i < touches.Count; i++)
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
    TouchPhase phase = touch.phase;

    PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    eventDataCurrentPosition.position = touch.position;

    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);

    var touchOnThisObject = results.Any(x => x.gameObject.name.ToLower() == this.gameObject.name.ToLower());
    if (!touchOnThisObject)
        return;

    if (phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        this.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
    }
    if (phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        this.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.blue;
    }
}
```

Are there any tutorial for my architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution :)

Thank you Bro @IsGreen

Source : http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-raycast-multitouch-input-convert-local-recttransform-rect-to-screen-position.318115/

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class UImageRayCast : MonoBehaviour
{
Image image;
Color colorOn, colorOff;

void Start()
{
    this.image = this.GetComponent<Image>();
    this.colorOff = this.image.color;
    this.colorOn = new Color(this.colorOff.r, this.colorOff.g, this.colorOff.b, this.colorOff.a * 0.5f);
}

void Update()
{

    this.image.color = this.colorOff;

    PointerEventData pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    List<RaycastResult> raycastResult = new List<RaycastResult>();

    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        pointer.position = touch.position;
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResult);
        foreach (RaycastResult result in raycastResult)
        {
            if (result.gameObject == this.gameObject)
            {
                if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Began " + result.gameObject.name );
                }
                else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
                {
                    this.image.color = this.colorOn;
                }
                else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    Debug.Log("End  " + result.gameObject.name);
                }
                //this.gameObject.transform.position = touch.position;

                //Do Stuff

            }

        }

        raycastResult.Clear();

    }

}
```